# Modifying/ Manipulating Text Using sed, awk or vim

Tags: unix, vim, text, sed, awk

I am trying to manipulate this text file from:

```
>hg19_ct_UserTrack_3545_MACS_peak_2 range=chr1:777590-777790 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
TCCACCCACCGAAGTTGTTTGGTCCCAATCTGCAAAATCAGTTAAACGTC
TTCCTGCCTGGCAGCAGATCAAAGGGTGAGGGGTCTGGGACAGACAGAGA
CGGCTAGAGAATGGATGGTGAAGTGCTCAGAGGCCCTGTGGGCTATCCCA
```

To

```
>MACS_peak_2_range=chr1:777590-777790 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
TCCACCCACCGAAGTTGTTTGGTCCCAATCTGCAAAATCAGTTAAACGTC
TTCCTGCCTGGCAGCAGATCAAAGGGTGAGGGGTCTGGGACAGACAGAGA
CGGCTAGAGAATGGATGGTGAAGTGCTCAGAGGCCCTGTGGGCTATCCCA
```

I have been using sed and vim to get it but I can't get the combination of spaces or exact information I need for the first line (the programme doesn't work without it)

Thanks
Harriet

Comment: is `MACS_peak_2` dynamic ? is there any rule about this part?

Comment: To my knowledge there's no rule; at peak number xx, the DNA sequence is that listed below the heading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk (since Kent provided a sed solution)

```
awk '/^>/sub(/hg19_ct_UserTrack_3545_/, "")' input
```

To change the first space to a underscore, add another sub:

```
awk '/^>/sub(/hg19_ct_UserTrack_3545_/, "");sub(/ /, "_")' input
```

sed is probably a better solution to this problem.

Comment: There is also a space that would need to be changed to an underscore between `peak_2` and `range`according to the example.

Answer (score 1):

if `MACS_peak_2` is fixed string:

```
sed 's/>.*MACS/>MACS/; s/ /_/' file
```

would do the job:

```
kent$  echo ">hg19_ct_UserTrack_3545_MACS_peak_2 range=chr1:777590-777790 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
TCCACCCACCGAAGTTGTTTGGTCCCAATCTGCAAAATCAGTTAAACGTC
TTCCTGCCTGGCAGCAGATCAAAGGGTGAGGGGTCTGGGACAGACAGAGA
CGGCTAGAGAATGGATGGTGAAGTGCTCAGAGGCCCTGTGGGCTATCCCA"|sed 's/>.*MACS/>MACS/; s/ /_/'
>MACS_peak_2_range=chr1:777590-777790 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
TCCACCCACCGAAGTTGTTTGGTCCCAATCTGCAAAATCAGTTAAACGTC
TTCCTGCCTGGCAGCAGATCAAAGGGTGAGGGGTCTGGGACAGACAGAGA
CGGCTAGAGAATGGATGGTGAAGTGCTCAGAGGCCCTGTGGGCTATCCCA
```

if you would like to do it in **vim**:

```
:g/^>hg/s/hg.*MAC/MAC/|s/ /_/
```

this line would replace all lines start with `>hg`, try it.

Comment: No, MACS_peak_2 isn't fixed, the MACS_peak part is but the number changes (they're basically the name of the coordinates from which the text below is extracted from)

Comment: ok, doesn't matter, as long as `MACS` is fixed, the both solutions would work for you. try it.

Comment: thanks. I've tried the vim but I get a peculiar heading: >MACS_peak_718_range=chr19_gl000208_random:192-392 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
AATGAACCCTTGCAGATACTAGAGAAAGACTGTTTCAAAACTGCTCTATC
I need to keep the MACS_peak_2_range=chr1:777590-777790 exactly the same. Thanks

Comment: so you want every target header line has fixed `MACS_peak_2_range=chr1:777590-777790` ?

Comment: @user1879573 strange, the sed and vim lines give same result here. anyway, it is important when you say it worked. .. :)

Answer (score 0):

The below does an inplace replacement.after you the execute the command.the file will be changed.

```
perl -pe 's/^\>.*?(MACS_peak.*)/>$1/g' your_file
```

see below the test:

```
> cat temp
>hg19_ct_UserTrack_3545_MACS_peak_2 range=chr1:777590-777790 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
TCCACCCACCGAAGTTGTTTGGTCCCAATCTGCAAAATCAGTTAAACGTC
TTCCTGCCTGGCAGCAGATCAAAGGGTGAGGGGTCTGGGACAGACAGAGA
CGGCTAGAGAATGGATGGTGAAGTGCTCAGAGGCCCTGTGGGCTATCCCA
> 
> 
> 
> 
> perl -pe 's/^\>.*?(MACS_peak.*)/>$1/g' temp
>MACS_peak_2 range=chr1:777590-777790 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
TCCACCCACCGAAGTTGTTTGGTCCCAATCTGCAAAATCAGTTAAACGTC
TTCCTGCCTGGCAGCAGATCAAAGGGTGAGGGGTCTGGGACAGACAGAGA
CGGCTAGAGAATGGATGGTGAAGTGCTCAGAGGCCCTGTGGGCTATCCCA
> 
> 
> 
> perl -pi -e 's/^\>.*?(MACS_peak.*)/>$1/g' temp
> 
> 
> 
> cat temp
>MACS_peak_2 range=chr1:777590-777790 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
TCCACCCACCGAAGTTGTTTGGTCCCAATCTGCAAAATCAGTTAAACGTC
TTCCTGCCTGGCAGCAGATCAAAGGGTGAGGGGTCTGGGACAGACAGAGA
CGGCTAGAGAATGGATGGTGAAGTGCTCAGAGGCCCTGTGGGCTATCCCA
>
```