# Modifying/ manipulating text using vim, sed or awk (again)

Tags: vim, text, sed, awk

Sorry one more quick question regarding the previous one - 
I want to add in an underscore between the peak number and range. I'm getting odd results from vim.

> MACS_peak_1 range=chr1:569425-569625 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
>   TTCGCTCTAAGATTAAAAATGCCCTAGCCCACTTCTTACCACAAGGCACA
>   CCTACACCCCTTATCCCTATACTAGTTATTATCGAAACCATCAGCCTACT

to

> MACS_peak_1_range=chr1:569425-569625 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
>   TTCGCTCTAAGATTAAAAATGCCCTAGCCCACTTCTTACCACAAGGCACA
>   CCTACACCCCTTATCCCTATACTAGTTATTATCGAAACCATCAGCCTACT

Thank you
Harriet

Comment: I doubt if many people know what your previous question was and your expected output seems to be identical to your sample input. If it's not, how about coming up with some sample input that highlights your actual problem more clearly? I doubt it the input has to be 100 characters long or whatever that is you posted to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Vim:
:%s/\(\d\) range/\1_range/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modifying/ Manipulating Text Using sed, awk or vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199399/modifying-manipulating-text-using-sed-awk-or-vim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '/MACS_peak/{$1=$1"_"$2;$2="";}1' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a shell:

```
sed -i s/"MACS_peak_1 range"/"MACS_peak_1_range"/g <filename>
```

Comment: It would be much simpler to drop the `g` flag.  In fact, you can probably get away with `sed 's/ /_/'`.

Comment: `sed 's/ /_/'` will replace all the spaces. I wanted to be sure that only the desired space is replaced. If there is only one occurrence, it works fine without the `g` flag.

Comment: No.  `sed 's/ /_/'` will replace only the first space.  `sed 's/ /_/g'` will replace all spaces.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I usually use the `g` flag and I've made a confusion.